# Video, but no audio on TV when connected to laptop over hdmi

Tags: audio, hdmi, speakers

I have a windows 10 laptop (Thinkpad E570) and a samsung smart tv (Samsung J6200). When I plug in an hdmi cable I can duplicate or extend the video just fine, but I can't get the sound to come out of the TV. It comes out of the laptop instead.

I have gone to audio devices, but the only one there is Contextant SmartAudio HD, which is the laptop. I have right clickced and show disconnected + disabled devices are both clicked; the tv is still not showing up. I have gone to device manager and looked at sound, video and game controllers; again, the only thing there is contextant audio. The TV simple doesn't show up as an audio device, although it does show up as generic pnp monitor.

I know my hardware is compatible. When I boot ubuntu on the same laptop with the same cable, it works fine. When I use my old laptop which also runs windows 10, with the same hdmi cable, it works fine and samsung tv shows up as an audio device. I just can't get the samsung tv to show up as an audio device on windows on my new laptop. Any ideas?

Comment: Try stopping any running Hyper-V services.  If that doesn't help, try uninstalling hyper-v entirely (its harmless enough).  It sounds crazy but try it.  If it works for you please let me know and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: There's no hyper-v services running in services.msc (some show up, but are not active) and I don't think they're even enabled. In "windows features", hyper-v is not checked. It doesn't show up in uninstall programs either.

Comment: Are you using integrated Intel graphics or discrete Nvidia?  The audio and video subsystems are separate in a PC. The HDMI port is under the video subsystem control.

Comment: Integrated (Intel HD Graphics 620).